# Resource Path Location : Type CPLEX(default) cannot extract expression

Tags: opl

I'm getting the error:

> CPLEX(default) cannot extract expression

on the expression

```
"minimize (1 / 2)*(sum(i in 923..931, j in 1..18, k in 923..931, l in 1..18) (((f[i]*s[i][k])*d[j][l])*x[i][j])*x[k][l])+(1 / 2)*(sum(i in 1..922, j in 1..18, k in 923..931, l in 1..18) (((f[i]*s[i][k])*d[j][l])*y[i][j])*x[k][l])+(1 / 2)*(sum(i in 923..931, j in 1..18, k in 1..922, l in 1..18) (((f[i]*s[i][k])*d[j][l])*x[i][j])*y[k][l])+sum(i in 923..931, j in 1..18) (f[i]*rs[j])*x"[i][j]."
```

Can anyone help me? I already try to use "using CP;" but it didn't work.

My code is the following:

```
 // Indices, Parameters and variables

 int  Nbeitems=...;
 int  Nbnitems=...;
 int  Nbcorridors=...;

 range nitems = Nbeitems+1..Nbeitems+Nbnitems;
 range eitems = 1..Nbeitems;
 range corridors = 1..Nbcorridors;

 dvar boolean x[nitems][corridors];

 float y[eitems][corridors]=...;
 float f[nitems]=...;
 float s[nitems][nitems]=...;
 float d[corridors][corridors]=...;
 float rs[corridors]=...;
 float S[nitems]=...;


 // objective funtion
minimize 1/2*sum(i in nitems,j in corridors, k in nitems,l in corridors) f[i]*s[i][k]*d[j][l]*x[i][j]*x[k][l]+1/2*sum(i in eitems,j in corridors,k in nitems,l in corridors) f[i]*s[i][k]*d[j][l]*y[i][j]*x[k][l]+1/2*sum(i in nitems,j in corridors,k in eitems,l in corridors) f[i]*s[i][k]*d[j][l]*x[i][j]*y[k][l] + sum(i in nitems, j in corridors) f[i]*rs[j]*x[i][j];

// constraints
subject to
{ forall (j in corridors)
    ctEachitemhasoneslot:
        sum (i in eitems) y[i][j] + sum (i in nitems) x[i][j] <= 90;

  forall (i in nitems)
    ctEachitemhasstorenecessities:
        sum(j in corridors) x[i][j]==S[i];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

similar question at https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/523660/cplexdefault-cannot-extract-expression.html?utm_campaign=answers&utm_medium=email&utm_source=answers-new-question&utm_content=answers-answer-question

in your objective you have out of range. But if you write

```
 minimize 1/2*sum(i in nitems,j in corridors, k in nitems,l in corridors) 
  f[i]*s[i][k]*d[j][l]*x[i][j]*x[k][l]+1/2*
  sum(i in eitems,j in corridors,k in nitems,l in corridors:i in nitems) 
  f[i]*s[i][k]*d[j][l]*y[i][j]*x[k][l]+
  1/2*sum(i in nitems,j in corridors,k in eitems,l in corridors:k in nitems) f[i]*s[i][k]*d[j][l]*x[i][j]*y[k][l] + 
  sum(i in nitems, j in corridors) f[i]*rs[j]*x[i][j];
```

Then they will go away